# precast construction, shear force and home gym

Tags: shear, forces

I have home gym machine (see below). I am in building constructed with precast construction (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precast_concrete). Builder has refused me to assemble the equipment because of "shear force". Is it really valid argument and if yes, is there a way to reduce it by using say rubber flooring?

**EDIT August 19 2022**

The one liner I got from builder is "It's a home gym equipment and can't be allowed due to punching load as suggested by consultant"

The total weights on machine is 60 KG.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: The best advice is to engage a structural engineer to perform an evaluation and provide recommendations.

Comment: "*shear force...is there a way to reduce it by using say rubber flooring?*" ??? What? You're definitely out of your element here if this is your thought process. Do not trust any judgement you have regarding this. Get help. There's no way to convey the required information online anyways. Someone needs to see the location. Did the builder even say anything about pre-cast concrete? Or did you bring that up yourself? Because bridges are built from pre-cast concrete but that doesn't mean the builder did not see something peculiar about your building. This is like those aquarium or piano questions

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes, I _definitely_ out of my element :) I have edited question and added one liner I got. Does that help?

Comment: Is this "Builder" the builder of the building or builder of the equipment? The terminology is a bit unclear but I must assume you are talking about the builder of the building, right? If they got a consultant it's pretty difficult to argue against that.

Comment: @DKNguyen yes. Builder\developer of building. They have "consultants" :)

Comment: It could also be related to the location you want to place it in. I can't imagine that being heavier than a piano.

Comment: @DKNguyen The total weights on machine is 60 KG - I have edited the question as well.